# Get value before replace in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to get value from string before I replace the string with other value in Python using regex, but I don't know how to do it.

For example:

Original String:

> This is 123 and that is ABC.
>
> This is 456 and that is OPQ.

I want to extract 123 and 456 and then replace '*This is 123*' and '*This is 456*'to '*That was XYZ*'

The result is pair list such as:

> 123 : That was XYZ and that is ABC.
>
> 456 : That was XYZ and that is OPQ.

Above is one very simple example, the extracted and replaced string might be more complicate in my case.

Is it possible use Regex to do it in Python ?

My original idea is use re.findall to find all number, and then use sub to replace the string. But the question is that I am not sure if it possible to paired the replaced string and the number.

Thank you for your answering.

Comment: Please pick a better example, I assume your real code uses a regexp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> strs = "This is 123 and that is ABC."
>>> match = re.search(r'.*?(\d+)',strs)
>>> rep = match.group(0)
>>> num = match.group(1)
>>> "{}: {}".format(num, re.sub(rep,'That was XYZ',strs))
'123: That was XYZ and that is ABC.'

>>> strs = 'This is 456 and that is OPQ.'
>>> match = re.search(r'.*?(\d+)',strs)
>>> rep = match.group(0)
>>> num = match.group(1)
>>> "{}: {}".format(num, re.sub(rep,'That was XYZ',strs))
'456: That was XYZ and that is OPQ.'
```

Comment: Unless `re.sub` count is `1`, you should use `re.findall` instead of `re.search`

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "This is 123 and that is ABC."
match = re.search("\d+", string).group()
string = match+":"+string.replace(match, "XYZ")
```

Considering the match happens for sure, else you can put an if condition around match

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like:

```
In [1]: s = 'This is 123 and that is ABC.'

In [2]: patt = re.compile('This is (?P<number>\d+)')

In [3]: patt.findall(s)
Out[3]: ['123']

In [4]: patt.sub('That was XYZ', s)
Out[4]: 'That was XYZ and that is ABC.'
```

You can then wrap this into simple function that returns tuple with your number and replaced string.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way is to use replace function

```
def f(match):
    print match.group(1)
    return 'That was XYZ'

re.sub('This is (\d+)', f, strs)
```